# Imitate Request with python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to imitate a request

```
POST /default/latex2image HTTP/2
Host: e1kf0882p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Length: 96
Sec-Ch-Ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="104"
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Origin: https://latex2image.joeraut.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://latex2image.joeraut.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9

{"latexInput":"\\begin{align*}\n{1}\n\\end{align*}\n",
"outputFormat":"PNG",
"outputScale":"125%"}
```

When its sent from the original brower, there is no problem.
However when I try to do it in python, the server rejects the request, and I don't know why.

This is what I tried:

```
pload = {
"latexInput":"{0}",
"outputFormat":"PNG",
"outputScale":"125%"
}

header = {
"Content-Length": "96",
"Sec-Ch-Ua": "Not A;Brand;v=99, Chromium;v=104",
"Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile":"?0",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36",
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "Windows",
"Origin": "https://latex2image.joeraut.com",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Referer": "https://latex2image.joeraut.com/",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language": "es-ES,es;q=0.9",
}
r = requests.post("http://e1kf0882p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", data=pload, headers=header)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

And the error it raised:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='e1kf0882p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 
port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000259A4D20670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una 
conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión'))
```

Comment: Port 80 is not open on `http://e1kf0882p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` if I try with `https://e1kf0882p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` I get a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Please specify what is suppose to be inside of the `latexInput`? `"latexInput":"{0}",` doesn't make much sense and neither does `"latexInput":"\\begin{align*}\n{1}\n\\end{align*}\n"`

Comment: Huh its true. So is there a wey to know what port it uses with the browser? For information, my browser is chrome

Comment: latexInput refers to latex code, like {1} is a number. Or another example  \frac{1}{2} is a fraction

Comment: Posting to `https://e1kf0882p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/latex2image` gives an internal server error, my guess is that the server only accepts requests from `https://latex2image.joeraut.com`.

Comment: So is there a wey to try make it belive its from the original url with python, or it is illegal?

Comment: No that's not possible as far as I know.

Comment: if you want to zoom, email me yishai rasowsky at gmail